# JavaFX - Only one label is showing

Tags: java, javafx, position, label, missing-data

**EDIT: SOLVED, ACCIDENTALLY FLIPPED X AND Y VALUES FOR LABEL'S 1 & 2**

I'm creating an overlay using JavaFX, but for some reason two of my labels are missing while one is perfectly fine. It's weird because they all have the same y-value (setLayoutY) and only one label is successfully shown. When changing label 1's y-value from 536 to 500, it then gets show, but cut out.

When label 1's setLayoutY(536): https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJeey.png
When label 2's setLayoutY(500): https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYMNb.png

It's weird because it's well within both the pane and stages size (by the way, which one takes *precedence*). On the other hand, label 2 has the same y-value of 536 and is displayed, but the rest aren't.

I really hope this isn't a simple mistake as I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thank you!

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Overlay extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setPrefSize(765,596);

        Label label1 = new Label("why does");
        label1.setLayoutX(97);
        label1.setLayoutY(536);
        label1.setPrefWidth(57);
        label1.setPrefHeight(184);
        label1.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);

        Label label2 = new Label("this happen");
        label2.setLayoutX(481);
        label2.setLayoutY(536);
        label2.setPrefWidth(184);
        label2.setPrefHeight(57);
        label2.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);

        Label label3 = new Label("-1");
        label3.setLayoutX(289);
        label3.setLayoutY(536);
        label3.setPrefWidth(57);
        label3.setPrefHeight(184);
        label3.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);


        root.getChildren().addAll(label1, label2, label3);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 765, 596, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Set same PrefHeight in all label**

```
label1.setPrefHeight(57);
label2.setPrefHeight(57);
label3.setPrefHeight(57);
```

Comment: I flipped the x and y values mistakenly, thank you very much!